# Presto cluster cannot run queries against hive defined tables - "No nodes available to run query"

Tags: hive, emr, presto

I am running a 2 node presto cluster pointed to hive on EMR, which is configured with data on S3.

The hive metadata is visible; in the CLI I can describe (table) claim1, and see metadata about it.

Both nodes show up as active in the sys.node table.

When I run a query (select count(*) from claim1 where col1='M'), I see a lot of logging on the coordinator node, finishing with:

```
2014-05-19T22:19:32.760+0000     INFO   HiveHdfsWalker-144  stdout  22:19:32.760 [HiveHdfsWalker-144] DEBUG c.a.s.s.m.t.XmlResponsesSaxParser - Examining listing for bucket: unzippeddata

2014-05-19T22:19:32.763+0000     INFO   HiveHdfsWalker-144  stdout  22:19:32.763 [HiveHdfsWalker-144] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: 9B844EEC8586FF3B

2014-05-19T22:19:32.766+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-8   com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Stage 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.1 is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:19:32.766+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-6   com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Stage 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.0 is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:19:32.768+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-7   com.facebook.presto.execution.QueryStateMachine Query 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:19:32.770+0000    ERROR   Stage-20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.1-126 com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Error while starting stage 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.1
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: No nodes available to run query
    at com.facebook.presto.util.Failures.checkCondition(Failures.java:79) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.util.Failures.checkCondition(Failures.java:73) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.NodeScheduler$NodeSelector.computeAssignments(NodeScheduler.java:184) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.scheduleSourcePartitionedNodes(SqlStageExecution.java:631) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.startTasks(SqlStageExecution.java:549) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.access$200(SqlStageExecution.java:91) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution$4.run(SqlStageExecution.java:521) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
2014-05-19T22:19:32.775+0000     INFO   query-scheduler-7   com.facebook.presto.event.query.QueryMonitor    TIMELINE: Query 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx :: elapsed 483.00ms :: planning 74.12ms :: scheduling 409.00ms :: running 0.00ms :: finishing 409.00ms :: begin 2014-05-19T22:19:32.285Z :: end 2014-05-19T22:19:32.768Z
2014-05-19T22:19:32.872+0000    DEBUG   task-notification-0 com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskStateMachine  Task 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.0.0 is CANCELED
2014-05-19T22:19:32.880+0000    DEBUG   20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.0.0-0-56    com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor  Split 20140519_221932_00005_mfhtx.0.0-0 (start = 1400537972443, wall = 437 ms, cpu = 3 ms, calls = 2) is finished
```

...or alternately:

```
2014-05-19T22:22:43.972+0000     INFO   HiveHdfsWalker-170  stdout  22:22:43.972 [HiveHdfsWalker-170] DEBUG c.a.s.s.m.t.XmlResponsesSaxParser - Parsing XML response document with handler: class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListBucketHandler

2014-05-19T22:22:43.972+0000     INFO   HiveHdfsWalker-170  stdout  22:22:43.972 [HiveHdfsWalker-170] DEBUG c.a.s.s.m.t.XmlResponsesSaxParser - Examining listing for bucket: unzippeddata

2014-05-19T22:22:43.976+0000     INFO   HiveHdfsWalker-170  stdout  22:22:43.976 [HiveHdfsWalker-170] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received successful response: 200, AWS Request ID: 476D4ABA552DAA66

2014-05-19T22:22:43.979+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-17  com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Stage 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.1 is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:22:43.979+0000    ERROR   Stage-20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.1-160 com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Error while starting stage 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.1
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: No nodes available to run query
    at com.facebook.presto.util.Failures.checkCondition(Failures.java:79) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.util.Failures.checkCondition(Failures.java:73) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.NodeScheduler$NodeSelector.computeAssignments(NodeScheduler.java:184) ~[presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.scheduleSourcePartitionedNodes(SqlStageExecution.java:631) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.startTasks(SqlStageExecution.java:549) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.access$200(SqlStageExecution.java:91) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution$4.run(SqlStageExecution.java:521) [presto-main-0.68.jar:0.68]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
2014-05-19T22:22:43.983+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-13  com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution Stage 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.0 is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:22:43.984+0000    DEBUG   query-scheduler-14  com.facebook.presto.execution.QueryStateMachine Query 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx is FAILED
2014-05-19T22:22:43.990+0000     INFO   query-scheduler-14  com.facebook.presto.event.query.QueryMonitor    TIMELINE: Query 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx :: elapsed 233.00ms :: planning 60.01ms :: scheduling 173.00ms :: running 0.00ms :: finishing 173.00ms :: begin 2014-05-19T22:22:43.751Z :: end 2014-05-19T22:22:43.984Z
2014-05-19T22:22:44.088+0000    DEBUG   task-notification-3 com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskStateMachine  Task 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.0.0 is CANCELED
2014-05-19T22:22:44.102+0000    DEBUG   20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.0.0-0-50    com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor  Split 20140519_222243_00007_mfhtx.0.0-0 (start = 1400538163839, wall = 259 ms, cpu = 0 ms, calls = 2) is finished
```

The non-coordinator node sometimes (but not consistently) gets a couple lines in its logs:

```
2014-05-19T22:19:32.340+0000    DEBUG   task-notification-10    com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskStateMachine  Task 20140519_222103_00006_mfhtx.0.0 is CANCELED
2014-05-19T22:19:32.352+0000    DEBUG   20140519_222103_00006_mfhtx.0.0-0-48    com.facebook.presto.execution.TaskExecutor  Split 20140519_222103_00006_mfhtx.0.0-0 (start = 1400538063009, wall = 343 ms, cpu = 0 ms, calls = 2) is finished
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem used to be caused by forgetting to configure `datasources` on the workers, but this is no longer a problem because Presto no longer requires explicit configuration for this (and the config property will likely be removed in a future release).

Comment: Dumb oversight on my part - thanks. Why did it manage to query  table metadata without this config?

Comment: This rather confusing config option specifies which nodes should process splits for a given data source. For example, you might have a set of machines that are closer to HDFS on the network and only want them to process Hive data, but you have another set that should only process the later stages of a query. However, this property is not a great way of accomplishing this and is confusing, so we plan to remove it in a future release (and introduce a better way of accomplishing the aforementioned task if the need arises).

Comment: I got the same issue. It worked after removing the "datasources" configuration form all the nodes.